# Calling progress or increase counter in configure method of reducer

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to do so ?

**Context:** My configure method for a reducer needs to read a set of files from DistributedCache (total size is ~150MB). However, I don't know why it takes so long that hadoop kill some reducers despite the fact that there are some reducers that have finished successfully.

I use the old API where I can only access the JobConf conf variable in the configure method.

My idea is to make the reporter variable a field then I can call it in the configure method. But it seems configure is called before reduce is called.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your code to use new API!

Then in `setup()`, you can access the `context` variable and call `progress()` as follows:

```
@Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
context.progress();
}
```